# Not able to print value using reference inside function in perl

Tags: perl

Why am i not being able to print the value using reference when its inside function?

```
sub fun {
    $ref = @_;
    print "\n Inside the function $ref->[1] \n";
}
my @arr=(2,3,4);
fun (\@arr);
my $ref2 = \@arr;
print "\n$ref2->[1]\n";
```

**Output i get is :**

```
Inside the function

3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is your assignment that is wrong:

```
$ref = @_;
```

Because in scalar context, an array returns its size, not its elements. Scalar context is imposed when you have a scalar value on the left hand side. You should do:

```
my ($ref) = @_;
```

Or

```
my $ref = shift;   # shifts first argument from @_
```

You also need to change `$ref->[1]` to `$ref->[0]`, or you will refer to the wrong element. Perl arrays start at index 0.

What you should have done is to use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Which would have given you the error:

```
Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at line ...
```

Which is what happens. You assign the size `1` to `$ref`, and then try to use it as an array ref: `$ref->[1]`